# Confused about variable scope in Bash

Tags: bash, variables, unix

this is my code inside a function

```
function safeChmod_ProcessOctalModes() {
    local i=0
    local targetpermission=""
    local chmod_param=$1
    # local folder_chmod_param=`echo $chmod_param | fold -w1`
    # echo xxxxxxxxxxxx=$folder_chmod_param >/dev/tty
    echo -n "$chmod_param" | \
    while read -n 1 ch;
    do
        if [ $i -eq 0 ]
        then
            i=$(( i+1 ))
            continue
        fi
        i=$(( i+1 ))

        if [ $ch -eq 0 ]
        then
            targetpermission=($targetpermission"---")
            echo tp=$targetpermission >/dev/tty
        elif [ $ch -eq 1 ]
        then
            targetpermission=($targetpermission"--x")
            echo tp=$targetpermission >/dev/tty
        elif [ $ch -eq 2 ]
        then
            targetpermission=($targetpermission"-w-")
            echo tp=$targetpermission >/dev/tty
        elif [ $ch -eq 3 ]
        then
            targetpermission=($targetpermission"-wx")
            echo tp=$targetpermission >/dev/tty
        elif [ $ch -eq 4 ]
        then
            targetpermission=($targetpermission"r--")
            echo tp=$targetpermission >/dev/tty
        elif [ $ch -eq 5 ]
        then
            targetpermission=($targetpermission"r-x")
            echo tp=$targetpermission >/dev/tty
        elif [ $ch -eq 6 ]
        then
            targetpermission=($targetpermission"rw-")
            echo tp=$targetpermission >/dev/tty
        elif [ $ch -eq 7 ]
        then
            targetpermission=($targetpermission"rwx")
            echo tp=$targetpermission >/dev/tty
        fi
    done 
    echo tp_in_func=$targetpermission >/dev/tty
    echo $targetpermission
    return 0;
}
```

Till I am within the while loop, `targetpermission` variable is populated correctly. But, as soon as the loop is done, the `targetpermission` is none.

This is the output.

```
chmod_param=0700
tp=rwx
tp=rwx---
tp=rwx------
tp_in_func=
```

Why is this happening ? How to I retain the`targetpermission` variable's assigned value outside the while loop ?

Comment: If you pipe into a while loop, the while loop will be in a subshell.

Comment: The pipe `|` causes the while loop to be executed as a parallel process, hence losing the variable when while loop ends. You can change it to `while (condition); do ... done <<< "$chmod_param"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
echo -n "$chmod_param" | \
while read -n 1 ch; do 
  #...
done
```

into

```
while read -n 1 ch; do 
  #...
done <<<"$chmod_param"
```

or more generally:

```
while read -n 1 ch; do 
   #...
done < <( echo -n "$chmod_param" )
```

to prevent the subshell creation that piping into a while loop results into.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen behavior like this before and it was due to certain constructs in bash creating a new context.  Basically anything that creates another shell, like the backtick operator or the $() operator have their own context.  In your case I think it might be the while loop being fed by echo.